# How to display a table using an ajax request

Tags: php, json, ajax, html-table

I've taken a sample of code from a similar question of another user and this partially relates to JSON as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
(function poll() {
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://localhost/scripts/query.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : {},
    dataType:'json',
    success : function(response) {
    var json_obj = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response));
    var output="";
    for (var i in json_obj) 
    {   
        output+="<tr>";
        output+="<td>" + json_obj[i].time.date + "</td>" + "<td>" + json_obj[i].username + "</td>" + "<td>" + json_obj[i].rics + "</td>" + "<td>" + json_obj[i].exclusive_rics +"</td>";
        output+="</tr>";
    }
    $('#table_content').html(output);
    },
    error : function(request,error)
    {
        alert("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request));
    } ,
    dataType: "json",
    complete: setTimeout(function() {poll()}, 5000),
    timeout: 2000
})
})();
```

My question is how do I send a JSON response in my PHP code such that I could store multiple users and print multiple rows of this data. So for example I have Heather, Larry, and George and wanted to print all the information related to these users in this fashion as demonstrated above. Also, how are the values of the object able to store 'username', 'date' and such.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

There is a json encode function you can use;

just set your return value to

`json_encode($array);`